# How to assign event handlers to multiple elements (colorPicker)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to find a way to assign event handlers to each box that I create dynamically. At the moment the user can click "Add above" or "Add below" and 2 rows of boxes will appear wherever they clicked.

I'm trying to make it so that when the user clicks on a specific square, a colorPicker will pop up and that specific square's color can be changed.

However, my program is a bit buggy, it only works for the first square that the user clicks on and the colorPicker never pops up again.

Does anyone know how I can go about fixing this or if there is a better alternative?

My code:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bwBRmw

```
var theParent = document.querySelector(".container");
theParent.addEventListener("click", doSomething, false)

//var picker = new Picker()
function doSomething(e) {
    console.log("gets inside doSomething")
    console.log(e.target)
    console.log(e.currentTarget)
    if (e.target !== e.currentTarget) {
        var clickedItem = e.target.id;
        console.log("Hello " + clickedItem);
        var k = document.getElementById(clickedItem)
        var picker = new Picker(k)
        picker.show();

    }
     picker.on_done = function(colour) {
        $(k).css('background-color',colour.rgba().toString());
        picker.hide()
        }

    //e.stopPropagation();
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code used to bind the click handler?

Comment: @GregBurghardt I have a link to it if that is okay with you:

http://iamsaravieira.com/picker.js

Comment: The `doSomething` function looks like it is being called as an event handler. Can you post the code that calls `doSomething` or binds this function as a click handler?

Comment: @GregBurghardt  var theParent = document.querySelector(".container");
    theParent.addEventListener("click", doSomething, false)

I also edited my initial post as I realized I didn't indent properly. Is the codepen link working for you?

Comment: Can you please add this to your question? Code in comments is often overlooked.

Comment: @GregBurghardt   Sure thing, just added it to the top of my code snippet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed in your CodePen that you didn't post the full code for `doSomething`. You have a problem because the `picker` variable is local to the function. If the code execution doesn't land inside the IF-statement, the picker variable is never created. Simply uncomment the code declaring the `picker` variable outside the function, and remove the `var` directive from in front of the line of code where you instantiate a new picker. Furthermore, you need to reset the "parent" element of the picker, since there is only one picker on the page: `picker.settings.parent = k;`

```
var picker = null; // Initialize global variable

function doSomething(e) {
    console.log("gets inside doSomething")
    console.log(e.target)
    console.log(e.currentTarget)
    if (e.target !== e.currentTarget) {
        var clickedItem = e.target.id;
        console.log("Hello " + clickedItem);
        var k = document.getElementById(clickedItem)

        // Reference the global "picker" variable
        if (!picker) {
          picker = new Picker(k)
        } else {
          // Set the "parent" element of the picker to the newly clicked element
          picker.settings.parent = k;
        }
        picker.show();

    }
     picker.on_done = function(colour) {
        $(k).css('background-color',colour.rgba().toString());
        picker.hide()
        }

    //e.stopPropagation();
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. Unfortunately, when I click on a specific square and then choose its color, I still can't click on another one. Do you know why this might be happening, in the console, I still see it reaching the if condition and it shows the id of the square that I am clicking on

Comment: @blazerix: I updated my answer. Have a look. I think all you need to do is reset the parent of the picker.

Comment: That seems to have done the trick, do you know why you have to reset the parent of the picker? Everytime I click on a square, it does enter the if condition and recognizes the id of the square I am clicking on.

Also, do you know why the colorPicker might not be working when I add multiple rows below?

Thanks for all the help by the way

Comment: The other questions would be better answered as further questions on StackOverflow.